# Moq, how to moq objects with private constructor?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, moq

I have this class hierarchy

```
public class Order
{  
    private Client _client;
    public virtual Client { get => _client; }

    private OrderNumber _orderNumber;
    public virtual OrderNumber OrderNumber { get => _orderNumber; }

    private ShippingDetails _shippingDetails;
    public virtual ShippingDetails ShippingDetails { get => _shippingDetails; }

    private IList<Product> _products;
    protected internal virtual IEnumerable<Product> Products { get => _products; }


    public Order() { }

    public virtual void CreateDraftForClient(int id)
    {
         /// => business rule validation of value 

         _client= new Client(id);

          /// => event     
     }
}

public class Client
{
    private int _id;
    public virtual int Id { get => _id; }

    private Client() { }
    protected internal Client(int id) 
    {
        SetId(id);
    }

    private void SetId(int id)
    {
        _id = id; 
    }
}
```

And want to create a fully initialized mock of order

```
 clientMock = new Mock<Client>();
 clientMock.SetupGet(prop => prop.Client).Returns(1);

 orderMock = new Mock<Order>();
 orderMock.SetupGet(prop => prop.Client).Returns(orderMock.Object);
```

Exception :

```
Message: System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Can not instantiate proxy of class: Client. Could not find a parameterless constructor.) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: eRxTestSetup testSetup)
---- Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: Client. Could not find a parameterless constructor.
---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: eRxTestSetup testSetup
```

Is there any way i can do so without having to change the structure of the Client? Or if not, what other options do I have ?

Comment: you could try creating it using reflection or create a derived class that calls the protected constructor

Comment: yes, this is the current situation, but i was hoping there is a solution out of the box

Comment: Ok this is feeling like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the end goal you are actually trying to achieve? What are you actually trying to test?

Comment: What I am trying to do is create some objects initialized with needed data for tests.  So I have a SetUp class and in this class constructor I'm creating mocks for each entity i have. The Setup class provides with a set of methods that initialize for example an Entity in different states and then returns the actual object Mock.Object. Example of method GetEntityInFullValidState(), which will use the EntityMock to create a fully initialized entity (all props and attributes). I've updated the classes, to my real scenario maybe it makes more sense

Comment: See if `clientMock = new Mock<Client>(1);` makes a difference.

Comment: it works, thanks a lot

Comment: Ok cool. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way for `Order` to be mocked given its current definition.

Try creating the mock through the protected constructor by passing the desired argument to the mock

```
int id = 1;
var clientMock = new Mock<Client>(id);
clientMock.SetupGet(prop => prop.Id).Returns(id);

var orderMock = new Mock<Order>();
orderMock.SetupGet(prop => prop.Client).Returns(clientMock.Object);
```